# What does this writing by the genie in Disney's Aladdin say?

Tags: disney, aladdin-1992

I was rewatching Aladdin the other day and caught the genie writing this:

[image: Arabic writing on an order pad, while impersonating a waiter]

What does it say?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/disney/comments/21vnob/i_just_watched_aladdin_for_the_first_time_since/

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### Persian for Turkey (and?) Rice (Pilaf)

According to User Arminius99 from the reddit post linked by @sumelic the **Persian** not Arabic writing would be made up of these letters:

> بوقلمون
>
> پلو

The user translated it as **Turkey Pilaf**

I ran the text through a lot of different translators and the first word always came out as **Turkey**

The second word however seems to vary between **Plates and Table** are the two results I got.

However typing "Pilaf" into google translate gives us this:[image]

This seems to me to be identical to that on the image:

[image]

Comment: Just googled: Pilaf is Middle Eastern for Pulav in India. I can imagine how delicious its!

Comment: Pilaf is simply a dish with two kinds of starch. Rice pilaf sinply means a pilaf where one of those starches is rice. It is common to see rice and very short pasta made into a pilaf

Comment: Is that Turkey the bird or Turkey the country?  Or are they still the same word in Persian?  (I've actually always wondered what the Turks called the bird, though I suppose being of new world origin, they might not be that common over there...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Well, the obvious way to check is to translate it into some other language where they're known to be different. Translating it into Turkish gives "Türkiye" whereas English "turkey sandwich" gives "Hindili sandviç".

Comment: The new world bird was named for the country of Turkey by various convolutions.

Comment: @Oldcat Really? So what did the Native Americans call it?

Comment: @MasonWheeler Most of the Old World named it after some random country where they *thought* it came from – and not a single one of them was right (Turkey, India, and Peru are the most common – Peru is almost-kinda close, but the bird they were talking about is from Mexico). Turkey and India were both convinced it was native to the *other*, if their words are anything to go by (Turkish *hindi* and Hindi *tarki*). Of course, the Aztecs, who were the original domesticators of the bird, weren’t helping much: they had a word for it, but that word is *huehxolotl*, which *can* be pronounced, I assume

Comment: @KRyan: That's old-school Spanish phonetics, where "x" used to be pronounced "sh".  How would you like some delicious weshalato for Thanksgiving and Christmas dinners?

Comment: @MasonWheeler - which tribe?  they spoke varied languages

Comment: @MasonWheeler - I looked it up in WIKI: In Blackfoot, it is called ómahksipi'kssíí, meaning “big bird”. In Cherokee (Tsalagi) it is called Gv-na(guh-nuh). In Cree, it is called misihew  "large  bird."
In Lakota, it is waglekšun.
In Miami, it is nalaaohki pileewa, meaning “native fowl”.
In Nahuatl, it is huehxōlōtl, which is reflected in Mexican Spanish as Guajolote.
In Ojibwe, it is mizise (ᒥᓯᐦᓭ / ᒥᓯᓭ) (plural: miziseg).
In Passamaquoddy, it is nem.
In Winnebago, it is Ziizíke.

Comment: The story I heard about the English name is that England got Guinea Fowl from Africa by "Turkish" traders - which might just be Islamic - and these were called Turkeys.  The similar new world bird just got the same name plastered onto it.

Comment: You're spot on, however a couple of things to clear up: **1.** It's Persian *and* Arabic writing (we share the same alphabet). **2.** It's "Pollo" which literally means rice, and not "Pilaf". Also to add clarification to some of the comments it's Turkey as in the bird, the Persian/Farsi word for the country is slightly different - "Torkiye". Source: I am Persian.

Comment: We'd always have Walking Bird on Thanksgiving. With all the trimmings!

Answer (score 22):

I am Persian; in this language, "بوقلمون" (pronounced *Booghalamoon*) is turkey (poultry), and "پلو" (pronounced *Polo*) is rice. This is a main food for Iranian (Persian) people. Rice in Persia (Iran) is served with meat or poultry or lamb.

Comment: As another Persian, I can confirm this answer.

Comment: @Mooz [I approve this message](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5_wCsDf_Hs)

Comment: nice to get the turkey is the bird not the country. i have eaten in multiple persian restaurants in usa -- not once was turkey on the menu -- guessing same in iran, that people do not eat much turkey in restaurants. exception is thanksgiving and x-mas. or sliced in sandwiches. many have confessed: turkey is not their favorite bird to eat.

Answer (score 1):

I am Arab > "بوقلمون" It looks like a quote from the Arabic word "لو تعلمون" 
which means "if you know" in Arabic language.

Comment: Hasn’t it already been confirmed as Persian, not Arabic, though?

Comment: @Adamant multi-lingual pun?

Answer (score -1):

Booghalamoon or بوقلمون is Persian for the bird "turkey". In old persia (and also modern Iran till sometimes in 1990s) tutkey was considered a delicacy. Alladin and the magic lamp is a part of 1001 night stories in Arabic, told by a Persian woman "Shahrzad" in Baghdad (nowadays Iraq) in the Abbasid era, when Persia in part, was under Islamic caliphate. Persian was the second language spokenafter Arabic. How the Persian version got into Alladin, not sure. Probably they asked a person who knew some Arabic (probably an Iranian person) living in LA and Working in Disney to write it down!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It seems there's already an answer that says this (and more).  To add a new answer you should add something different, that is not covered by the existing answer.